# mysql : select query with 'when case' or with 'if else' to get multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement of update a few columns when few conditions satisfies. Which one i should be using here? `CASE` or `IF-ELSE`?

Need to do something like this, not sure which one to use.
But in both cases i see the error "Couldn't return multiple columns":

```
IF colZ not like "%abc%" from table1
THEN
  Update table2 set colA = "A" and colB = "B"  
ELSE
  DONT DO ANYTHING(but should tel didnt do anything)
END

IF colZ not like "%abc%" from table1
THEN
  get t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col1,t3.col2 from table2 t2, table3 t3 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to do this is by using an `IF` statement:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE ColZ NOT LIKE '%abc%') > 0 THEN
    UPDATE Table2 SET ColA = 'A' AND ColB = 'B';
END IF;
```

This way if the `NOT LIKE` condition is satisfied for at least one row in Table1, the `UPDATE` statement will be executed. But be careful, if you use `UPDATE SET` without a `WHERE`, all the rows in Table2 will be affected.

Note that the `IF` statement can be used only in stored programs, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html